# difference between using SDL and using media player class that is videoview

Tags: android, ffmpeg, media-player, sdl

I have been surfing the net for some time to get basic understanding of media framework in android. As part of this, to display video we have media player class or video view component which can easily display the video. When we have such solution provided by the framework itself, then why there are few components avaiable like SDL [ Simple Direct Media Layer], which claims the same functionality as video view?

How both are different?

Answer (score 1):

The main *raison d'etre* for SDL, just as for many other native libraries, is to make it easier to port existing projects to Android, or help to create a new cross-platform project. If your business plan is to produce an Android-only app, you will most likely get it easier and faster if you use the system media framework. You also have better chances to take full advantage of the system. But if you consider porting to other platforms (mobile or desktop), you should strongly consider SDL as a building block that can provide device-independent API and let you concentrate on your app logic.